# scope resolution operator doesn't give compile time error in php

Tags: php

i created a small PDO class and spent hours in debugging it and could not find a small typo which was causing every thing to fail. To demonstrate below is the buggy code.

```
    class MyPDO  extends PDO
{
    private static $instance = null;
    function  __construct(){
        try{
        parent::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=blog", "root", "");
        parent::setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'Exception in constructor'.print_r($e->trace(),true);
        }

    }

   static public function getDB(){
        if(self::$instance == null){
            self:$instance = new MyPDO();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function selectAll($sql){
            $stmt = self::$instance->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(":cat_id"=>1));
            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}
```

What i want to confirm that if any one has already seen it or is it a bug or it could be used for some thing else i have no knowledge of.

There is a problem with the following line i wrote.

> self:$instance = new MyPDO();

it should be the scope resolution operator with double colon i.e.

> self::$instance = new MyPDO();

To my surprise no warning or error is generated with a single colon .. If any one knows about this please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance you are defining a jump label (think [`goto`](http://php.net/goto)).

```
self:  $instance = new MyPDO();
```

And $instance will just become a local variable.

So yes, it is sort of a bug that you can use a reserved word for a label.

Comment: Thanks mario  i believe a goto label with an assingment would give error

Comment: @Gmolvi: Er, why? It provides a place in code to jump to. Why would it matter what the code _is_ that you jump to?

Comment: yes i understood it now. thanks , so it is not a bug ? its logical